# count column items in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count, group-by

I have a column called "WasCancelled" in a MySQL DB, it's of a Boolean type.

I save the number 0,1 and 2 to it.

**I need a query that will count how many one's, two's and zeros are there.**

for example:
my column:

```
WasCanceled
-----------
    0
    0
    1
    1
    1
    2
    0
    0   
    0
    2
    0
    0
    1
```

**I need the query to output:**

```
 number | times
 -------|------
  "0"   |   7
  "1"   |   4
  "2"   |   2
```

please help.

thank you.

Dave.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by grouping:

```
SELECT WasCancelled, COUNT(*)
FROM <Table>
GROUP BY WasCancelled
```

If you need more information, look here for details on [Group By](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-group-by.htm) and [Count](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-count-function.htm).

## Update

To include the question in the comments: to restrict on special values, you can add a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT WasCancelled, COUNT(*)
FROM <Table>
WHERE WasCancelled = "1"
GROUP BY WasCancelled
```

In further questions, please edit your overall question to include sub-questions or open new topics. Please read [How To Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

## Update 2

`SQL` also allows the `HAVING` clause, which is like `WHERE` but allows the comparison of aggregated values. See [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/having-vs-where-clause/) for details (e.g. you want to know which value appears more than 5 times, etc.).

Comment: one last question, if I want to count only the "1" values ?

Comment: i can accept it only in 6 minutes, don't worry i will !

Comment: haha just wanted to mention since many people forget :) your second question: you can add a `WHERE` clause. I will update my answer. If you have more questions, please open another topic for them, since sub-questions should always be asked seperately.

Comment: can you look at this one for me please? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27500712/creating-a-custome-resault-set-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Use **GROUP BY** with **COUNT** fuction:

Try this:

```
SELECT WasCanceled, COUNT(1) as times 
FROM tableA 
GROUP BY WasCanceled;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work!

```
select
  count(WasCanceled) as CNT, WasCancelled
from
  YourTableNameHere
group by
  WasCanceled
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
SELECT WasCanceled AS number, COUNT(WasCanceled) AS times FROM tblTest GROUP BY WasCanceled
```