# Creating a custom result set in MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, jtable

I'm building an app that calculates the monthly bill amount for clients.

I am getting all data from MySQL in 3 different queries to populate 1 table.

I wanted to know if there is a way to join these queries, and create a result set with a default table of my choice.

**For example, I use these quires separately, and the data goes to the same table.**

```
// this will get me the prices per hour for the client.

select * from RoomManager.CompanyFinance where ProjectName = 'xxx';

the output will be something like:
ShiftType | Price
----------|------
  OL      |  555
  OFF     |  548
  BKG     |  666
  SND     |  422

//this will get me the amount of products per product for the client to this month.

SELECT ShiftType, COUNT(*) FROM RoomManager.dailyrooms
WHERE Project = 'xxx' 
AND Company = 'yyy'
AND DayDate LIKE \"%yyyy-dd%"                               
GROUP BY ShiftType;";

the output will be something like:
ShiftType | COUNT
----------|------
  OL      |  2
  OFF     |  1
  BKG     |  0
  SND     |  3

//this will get me the amount of cancellations

SELECT WasCancelled, COUNT(*) FROM RoomManager.dailyrooms
WHERE WasCancelled = 2 
AND Project = 'xxx'
GROUP BY WasCancelled;

the output will be something like:
WasCancelled | COUNT
-------------|------
  2          |  6
```

Is there a way to combine queries and get a single result set, something like this:

```
ShiftType | Price | COUNT | Was Cancelled
----------|---------------|--------------
  OL      |  555  |   2   |       6
  OFF     |  548  |   1   |
  BKG     |  666  |   0   |
  SND     |  422  |   3   |
```

Comment: What's the table structure or your RoomManager-table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My bad, `UNION` basically concats resultsets. You wanted to customize the result set (something like that):

> SELECT Orders.OrderID, Customers.CustomerName, Orders.OrderDate FROM Orders INNER JOIN Customers ON Orders.CustomerID=Customers.CustomerID;

`JOIN` combines the two tables by a common field, such as your ProjectName and Project field, allowing the SQL engine to combine the two different results into one result identified by the common field.

See: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

NOTE: I'm writing 'something like that' because it is an example, not a solution. It's aimed to show you a possibility to combine fields of two or more tables - it's still up to you to do the work and get it running for your specific case.

---

Old (incorrect for this case) answer:

A possible way might be to use MySQL's `UNION` keyword:

> SELECT * FROM mySchema.myTable UNION SELECT * FROM mySchema.myOtherTable

See: http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx

Comment: Am i wrong or did `union` write the results under each other, not side by side?

Comment: My bad, misread the question. Here you go (update coming in a few minutes)